# itertools/ groupby/ for loop

Tags: python, python-itertools

I've been recently trying to find a better way to check, whether a `group` has already been processed or not. The intended line is in the code shown below (`if (key == group[0][0]):`).
The idea that I'm trying to implement is the following:

it must be checked with every round of the loop `for group in groups`, if the condition mentioned above is fulfilled. So after all items in the first group have already been printed, the for loop will jump to the next group and do the same(after checking out the second condition `if (key == item[0]):`). The point thereby is to prevent the for loop from jumping to the next group, since there is no match between the key and the first element of each item, which means; no elements will be found or printed there. With that being said, I'm then avoiding not to jump into any other group that has an another key, saving time and memory.

So the question is; if there could be a better way to implement the idea, cause my own phrased condition is kind of a primitive one (checking if the first word is the same as the key one).

Many thanks in advance!

```
things = [("animal", "lion"), ("object", "computer"), ("animal", "giraffe"), ("animal","tiger"),("object","table"),("clothes", "jacket"), ("animal", "dog")]
sorted_things = sorted(things)
groups = []
special_keys = []
for key, group in groupby(sorted_things, lambda x: x[0]):
    groups.append(list(group))
    special_keys.append(key)
counting = 0
for key in special_keys:
    print("These things are to this key " + key + " sorted: ")
    for group in groups:
        if (key == group[0][0]):
            for item in group:
                if (key == item[0]):
                    print("                                          ",item[1])
```

and here's the output:

```
These things are to this key animal sorted:
                                           dog
                                           giraffe
                                           lion
                                           tiger
These things are to this key clothes sorted:
                                           jacket
These things are to this key object sorted:
                                           computer
                                           table
```

Comment: You should give some more background on your problem, including what you mean by "check" and "process".

Comment: `if` statements in Python do not use parentheses.

Comment: Are you aware of `collections.defaultdict`?

Answer (score 3):

> So the question is; if there could be a better way to implement the idea

Here's what I would do to obtain the same output:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

sorted_things = [
 ('animal', 'dog'),
 ('animal', 'giraffe'),
 ('animal', 'lion'),
 ('animal', 'tiger'),
 ('clothes', 'jacket'),
 ('object', 'computer'),
 ('object', 'table'),
]

for key, values in groupby(sorted_things, key=itemgetter(0)):
    print(f'These things are to this key {key} sorted:')
    for key, value in values:
        print(' ' * 42, value)
```

Note that the *groupby()* function already has the logic, "after all items in the first group have already been printed, the for loop will jump to the next group."

There is no need to check the first element to match the key.  The *groupby()* function already does that for you.